# Truncate the text with ellipsis but preserving the last word

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My use case: I want to display a text, limiting it to the maximum number of lines to two and truncating it with ellipsis only when it doesnt fit in the two lines, but I want to preserve the last word. I have to do this with multiple paras in the page.

eg:

Lorem asa ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam consectetur venenatis blandit. Praesent vehicula, libero non pretium vulputate, lacus arcu facilisis lectus, sed feugiat te... volutpat.

Algorithm I was thinking of:

```
<div class="outter">
        <div class="message" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.">
            <div class="firstLine"></div>
            <div class="secondLine" style="text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;"></div><div class="lastWord"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

1. Get the *outter* div length in pixel using  *obj.offsetWidth;*
2. Fetch the message from *message* div.
3. Find the length of string, and multiply with with approx 8 (one letter is approx 5 to 8 pixel )and compare it with *outter* the element width.
4. If the length of string is greater than the twice the length of *outter* div, then spilt the string (this is tricky as we would want to split based on space), put the first half in *firstLine* div and second half in *secondLine* div and last word in *lastWord* div. (This part won't work perfectly as we don't know the exact pixel length of string )*
5. But if string length is slightly lesser than twice the length of *outter* div, then the presentation will look ugly, as the second half + lastWord can either fit the secondLine div or requires both divs *secondLine* and *lastWord* div

Point me if there is any other way.

Comment: Show your attempt. If you haven't made any, come back when you have, show it, explain how exactly it fails and we can surely help.

Comment: Do you want to hide intermediate words in the text?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov yes only when if it doesn't fit in two lines.

Comment: I suppose only js will help

Comment: @s.kuznetsov yeah, but  I think it wont give seem less experience.

Comment: @connexo can you review  my approach and suggest anything can be dont better? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use .length to get the length of the string and a substring at that length and put an ellipsis there.

Check this if it works.
Thanks!